# Add new Virtual Directories to an Azure WebApp programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Is it possible to add a Virtual Directory to an Azure Web Apps Website using Azure SDK or Azure REST API?

We have a ASP.NET CMS website (the main site is at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) which has the ability to create new website instances pointing to the same source code as the main site with a level 1 virtual directory name (e.g. [www.example.com/project1](http://www.example.com/project1)). Each virtual directory will have its own users and administration.

I'm able to add a virtual directory manually in the Azure portal. I'm also able to use .NET API to create it programmatically in my local IIS (**ServerManager** from **Microsoft.Web.Administration**), but it doesn't work in Azure Web Apps.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use management rest api to create a virtual directory to azure webapp.

```
public void CreateVD(string name)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format(@"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{2}/config/web?api-version=2015-08-01",subscriptionId,webSpaceName,webSiteName));
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-03-01");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var token = GetAuthorizationHeader();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);

        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        string data = "";
        using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
              System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
              data = sr.ReadToEnd();
              sr.Close();
              stream.Close();
              Console.WriteLine("data found");
        }

        if (data == "")
        {
              Console.WriteLine("Error in collecting data");
                    return;
        }

        string path = name, directory = name;
        data = data.Replace("virtualApplications\":[", "virtualApplications\":[{\"virtualPath\":\"/" + path + "\",\"physicalPath\":\"site\\\\wwwroot\\\\" + directory + "\",\"preloadEnabled\":false,\"virtualDirectories\":null},");
        request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(String.Format(@"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{2}/config/web?api-version=2015-08-01",subscriptionId,webSpaceName,webSiteName));
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2013-03-01");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        request.Accept = "Accept=application/json";
        request.SendChunked = false;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Method = "PUT";

        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(data);
        sw.Close();

        response = request.GetResponse();

        using (System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
             data = (new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
             Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
   }
}
```

For the access token, you could use following code to get the token.

```
private string GetAuthorizationHeader()
{
    AuthenticationResult result = null;

    var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(loginpath, tenantId));

    result = context.AcquireToken(apiEndpoint, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri));
    }
```